# Is it possible to define a ValueConversion on a private field?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

EF Core lets you specify a private field to use in the database using string syntax:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property("myField");
```

And you can specify value conversions for properties:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<MyEntity>()
    .Property(e => e.MyProperty)
    .HasConversion(
        v => v.ToInt(),
        v => new MyProperty(v));
```

But is it possible to specify a value conversion for a private field? This doesn't compile, presumably because the type is unknown:

```
// won't work
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property("myField")
    .HasConversion(
        v => v.ToInt(),
        v => new MyFieldType(v));
```

Nor can you use the generic type parameter, because those are for predefined value converters provided by EF Core:

```
// won't work
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property("myField")
    .HasConversion<MyFieldType>(
        v => v.ToInt(),
        v => new MyFieldType(v));
```

Is it possible to define a ValueConversion on a private field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> EF Core lets you specify a private field to use in the database using string syntax

It also allows you to specify the property type:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
    .Property<MyFieldType>("myField")
//                 ^
```

Now all the standard typed value converter fluent APIs work:

```
.HasConversion(
    v => v.ToInt(),
    v => new MyProperty(v));
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan! This way is even better

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just have to define a new ValueConverter first:

```
ValueConverter<MyFieldType, int> myConverter = new ValueConverter<MyFieldType, int>(
    v => v.ToInt(),
    v => new MyFieldType(v));

modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
    .Property("myField")
    .HasConversion(myConverter);
```